# 'An unknown error occurred' deleting SQL database

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to delete a GCP SQL database, but I get the following error:

> An unknown error occurred

After attempting to delete the database, it has been set to 'Single User' mode.

I am able to set it back to 'Multi User' mode, but still unable to delete the database.

This is what I've tried. On the SQL instance in GCP:

1. Go to the databases tab
2. On the database in question, click on the 3 dots and select delete
3. Enter the database name
4. Click 'Delete'

Comment: My guess is that in step 2, when you select *the database in question*, you're making that database active, and it's not letting you delete the active database (which would be like cutting the tree branch you're standing on between you and the tree). As step 3 says that you have to enter the database name to delete, select a different database in step 2, and then enter the name of the database you want to delete. Does that change things?

Comment: Why have you also tagged SQL Server if you are using GCP?

Comment: I expect there will be additional information available in the logs...